# How can I open programms e.g. Skype minimized with a command line?

Tags: command-line

I am configuring shortcuts and just thought that it would be awesome to be able to open skype, thunderbird and this stuff minimized with a command-line-shortcut? Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: `skype &` to launch it, in settings you can tell it to start minimized, not sure that is the solution you want...

Comment: The below answers look good, I would just add that, once you get the proper command figured out create and alias to make it a short command: http://www.howtogeek.com/73768/how-to-use-aliases-to-customize-ubuntu-commands/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open skype in the command line:

```
nohup skype &
```

To open it minimized:

In Settings - General check the box that is labeled "Start Skype minimized in the system tray." That should get it to open minimized. (It does in gnome 3 at least)

Comment: easy command and just works :D thx

Comment: It does work with amarok, too but not with thunderbird. In Thunderbird there is also, I think, no option to open at minimized by default.

Comment: any possibility to fix that?

Comment: @ubuntu.stuff can you post it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a program minimized you can use `devilspie`

Install using

`sudo apt-get install devilspie`

Then make a directory inside your home

`mkdir ~/.devilspie`

Now let's say you to start a Skype minimized. To do this create a file called "terminal.ds" in the ~/.devilspie folder you've just created with following contents :

```
(if

    (is (application_name) "skype")
    (begin
       (minimize)
    )
)
```

Save this file and start devilspie  in terminal.
I have tested it as "Terminal" instead of "skype" as application name .